# Skybox Problems

Tags: hammer

When I compile and run my TF2 map I can see other parts of my map though the 3D Skybox wall I put at the edge of my map. Can someone help me fix this? There is suppose to be just sky there instead it show another part of my map.

[image: Picture from in Hammer]

[image: Picture from in Game]

I uploaded a picture of what it looks like in hammer and what it looks like in game.

Comment: Do you get any warnings when you compile the map? Sometimes this kind of thing happens if the BSP is not fully enclosed.

Comment: This website that's checks for errors say something about missing sky textures or something. There are no leaks I made sure of that.

Comment: When I run it through the website it gives me this.      "can't load skybox file skybox/sky_tf2_04 to build the default cubemap!
Description:
You have entered a skybox texture which doesn't seem to be valid. Make sure you don't specify the last three letter (_UP, _DN, etc) of any skybox texture you use. You may also need to fix your vmt files if they are broken. It may also be caused by compiling a non-HDR skybox texture.

Solution:
Fix $hdrbasetexture errors first
WIKI: Skybox 

The affected object may not work/appear properly
Last contribution: Anonymous"

Comment: everything in quotation marks.